# Is it possible to sub-parametrize pytest parameters values?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pytest, pytest-django

I'm working on a DRF (REST API) project and I'm using pytest. Quite often I find myself writing *almost* identical test parameters and I've been wondering if there's something I'm missing. I haven't read the entire pytest docs, although I definitely did read the entire django docs chapter on tests (not very helpful in my case) and I've now spent a few hours trying to find a solution. Let's assume I have a view like this:

```py
from rest_framework import generics
from myapp.permissions import IsStaff, IsAdmin

class MessagesListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsStaff | IsAdmin] 
    # ...
```

(Note: just for the example please assume that user with `IsAdmin` permission does not necessarily have `IsStaff` permission; this is not the point of the question.)

And for this view I wrote a test:

```
import pytest
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse_lazy
from pytest_lazy_fixture import lazy_fixture

class TestMessagesListViewPermissions:
    def get_response(self, client):
        url = reverse_lazy("api:messages-list")
        return client.get(url)
    
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        argnames=["client", "expected_response_status"],
        argvalues=[
            pytest.param(
                "anonymous_client",
                status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN,
            ),
            pytest.param(
                "authenticated_client",
                status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN,
            ),
            pytest.param(
                "staff_client",
                status.HTTP_200_OK,
            ),
            pytest.param(
                "admin_client",
                status.HTTP_200_OK,
            ),
        ],
    )
    def test__permissions(self, client, expected_response_status):
        # WHEN
        response = self.get_response(client)
        # THEN
        assert response.status_code == expected_response_status
```

And there are 4 different `client` values, but 1+2nd and 3+4th result in the same response status code. As I said, it's a simplified example, but what if there are 10 parameters? What I'd like to be able to do is something like this:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    argnames=["client", "expected_response_status"],
    argvalues=[
        pytest.param(
            ParamList["anonymous_client", "authenticated_client"],
            status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN,
        ),
        pytest.param(
            ParamList["staff_client", "admin_client"],
            status.HTTP_200_OK,
        ),
    ],
)
```

Is there any pytest feature I'm missing or a plugin that makes this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [pytest-subtests](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-subtests/)?

Here is a long discussion about its benefits and drawbacks: https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2020/04/subtests-in-python.html